# Is it possible to host multiple django projects under the same domain?

Tags: django, deployment, virtualenv, django-cms

I need to put different Django projects with Django CMS under the same domain, for example:

- example.com/2012/
- example.com/2014/

Normally I am using virtualenv and  mod_wsgi for each domain/project. I will need different databases, media files, and Django versions.

Putting projects under different subdomains is not an option here.

Is it possible to do? How should I setup the server? Are there any caveats I should know?

Comment: While not exactly a solution, you could consider using subdomains each having its own virtual hosts file

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

You can configure Apache / mod_wsgi to rewrite URLs and to direct them to different WSGI files. This allows you to setup entirely different virtualenvs, databases and Django versions for each site. For example:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /2012/ /location/to/my/files/website1.wsgi
WSGIScriptAlias /2014/ /location/to/my/files/website2.wsgi
```

Each of these WSGI files can then direct execution to files in a particular virtualenv with their own Django version and settings.

If you can loosen the constraint that you need different Django version then you can use the [`django.contrib.sites`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/) framework. This allows you to define multiple `Site` objects, once for each "website". You can then associate content with each of the sites while running one installation of Django.

Comment: As I wrote before, that will be two different projects with different Django versions: one of them as archived website and another one as actual website. So I won't be using the sites framework to separate them.

Comment: @AidasBendoraitis that's fair, I just mentioned it to make you aware. In that case the first setup with multiple WSGI settings should do what you need.

Comment: How will I need to define urls.py for those projects? Starting with `"^2012/"` or only what goes after that?

Comment: @AidasBendoraitis only what goes after that. Apache would take care of the year part.

Comment: With Django 1.3.3 reverse("any_view") returns a view without "/2012/" prefix so administration and all other views with forms don't work. Does this issue still appear with newer Django versions?