# Django served on specific URL - relative urls corrupted

Tags: python, django, routes, digital-ocean, wsgi

I've deployed my Django (DRF API) project on DigitalOcean apps. The path "/" is used by my static site that uses this API so I set route for this component to "/api" which works correctly.

The problem:

I go to `/api/admin/` and it redirects me to `/admin/login` but the `django` is served on `/api` url so this URL is invalid.

Do you know how to make this work?

Is there a way to tell `django` to use absolute URL everywhere?

Comment: There's some relevant information [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44987110/django-in-subdirectory-admin-site-is-not-working). But it's highly dependant on stack used.

Answer (score 0):

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path("api/admin/", admin.site.urls),
    ...
]
```

Comment: Thanks but no, the problem is more difficult. The `/api/` is in fact just `/` from Django project perspective. It's just served on `/api/` url but the project doesn't know about that.

Comment: The "/" and admin urls are hard coded in django.contrib.admin. Why don't you put it on a subdomain api.project.com? Unless you want to change Django/contrib/admin/sites.py :)

Comment: That's the way I will go, I was just curious if this is somehow possible.