# Django + Apache2 behind NGINX reverse proxy - redirections going wrong

Tags: django, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a Django project running on Apache2 with mod_wsgi in a VM - `https://systems3.slt.local/`

Accessing the VM directly, via `https://systems3.slt.local/` works perfectly. However, I need it to work behind an NGINX reverse proxy, and I'm having problems with login redirection.

My proxy is configured like this:

```
location /systems3 {
                 proxy_set_header Host $host;
                 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                 proxy_redirect off;
                 proxy_pass https://systems3.slt.local/;
         }
```

When I try to access the project through the proxy, `/systems3`, Django checks that there is no user logged in, and then redirects to `/accounts/login`. The correct would be to redirect to `/systems3/accounts/login/`. Even if I try to directly access this address, I am redirected to `/accounts/login`.

It seems that some configuration is missing so that the address `/systems3` is the root of the project, it shouldn't be redirecting me outside of systems3.

It's also giving problem with my static folder, it also looks for the folder at `/static`, ignoring that it was supposed to look inside `systems3`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django in subdirectory - admin site is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44987110/django-in-subdirectory-admin-site-is-not-working)

Comment: It partially worked. In addition to these settings, I needed to put LOGIN_URL = '/systems3/accounts/login' and LOGOUT_URL = '/systems3/accounts/logout' and STATIC_FILES_ROOT, STATIC_FILES_URLS, I needed to change to STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL. Tks.