# Deploying Multiple Django Websites with Apache & mod_wsgi Windows

Tags: python, django, apache, windows-server-2012-r2

I am using mod_wsgi in a virtualenv with Apache 2.4 and I want to serve multiple Django sites from the same server.

**httpd.config**

```
### Configuration Site_1
LoadModule wsgi_module " S:/Site_1/VirtualEnvSite_1/Lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp36-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
WSGIPythonHome "c:/users/mmyuser/appdata/local/programs/python/python36"
WSGIScriptAlias / " S:/Site_1/site_1/site_1/wsgi_windows.py"
WSGIPythonPath " S:/Site_1/VirtualEnvSite_1/Lib/site-packages"

Alias /static " S:/Site_1/site_1/staticfiles"
Alias /media " S:/Site_1/site_1/media"

<Directory " S:/Site_1/site_1/staticfiles">
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory " S:/Site_1/site_1/media">
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory " S:/Site_1/site_1/PEQ">
    <Files wsgi_windows.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

####Configuration Site_2
LoadModule wsgi_module " S:/Site_2/VirtualEnvSite_2/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp36-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
WSGIPythonHome "c:/users/myuser/appdata/local/programs/python/python36"
WSGIScriptAlias / " S:/Site_2/site_2/site_2/wsgi_windows.py"
WSGIPythonPath " S:/Site_2/VirtualEnvSite_2/Lib/site-packages"

Alias /static " S:/Site_2/site_2/staticfiles"
Alias /media " S:/Site_2/site_2/media"

<Directory " S:/Site_2/site_2/staticfiles">
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory " S:/Site_2/site_2/media">
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory " S:/Site_2/site_2/site_2">
    <Files wsgi_windows.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

**httpd-vhosts.config**

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

I have reviewed these posts:

1. [Deploying multiple django apps on Apache with mod_wsgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505576/deploying-multiple-django-apps-on-apache-with-mod-wsgi)
2. [multiple-django-sites-with-apache-mod-wsgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553165/multiple-django-sites-with-apache-mod-wsgi)
3. [running-multiple-django-projects-on-one-apache-instance-with-mod_wsgi/](https://www.xeve.de/wp/2018/03/running-multiple-django-projects-on-one-apache-instance-with-mod_wsgi/)
4. [Múltiples direcciones, un solo proyecto](https://programacionymas.com/blog/archivo-hosts-y-virtual-hosts-apache-windows)
5. [how-to-use-mod-wsgi-for-hosting-multiple-django-projects-under-single-domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56593673/how-to-use-mod-wsgi-for-hosting-multiple-django-projects-under-single-domain)

but they have not worked for me.

The server is a Windows Server 2012R2

Please direct me what I should do to get both sites up and running.

**Note:** The websites work perfectly separate

Comment: I have a similar problem! Individual applications run correctly using reverse proxy. But when I activate both, one of them gives the error: `AH00128: File does not exist: /var/www/html/myapp2/`. Configuration files are identical.

Answer (score 0):

I also have a similar problem. And I've already looked for many posts, one thing I noticed different from yours was the line:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / " S:/Site_1/site_1/site_1/wsgi_windows.py"
WSGIScriptAlias / " S:/Site_2/site_2/site_2/wsgi_windows.py"
```

I identify the site in the alias:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /site1 " S:/Site_1/site_1/site_1/wsgi_windows.py"
WSGIScriptAlias /site2 " S:/Site_2/site_2/site_2/wsgi_windows.py"
```

And I'm using process daemon:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /site1 /site1/wsgi.py
WSGIDaemonProcess site1_proc python-path=S:/Site_1/VirtualEnvSite_1/Lib/site-packages python-home="c:/users/mmyuser/appdata/local/programs/python/python36"
WSGIProcessGroup site1_proc
```

In my case it's still not working for some other reason. Which I haven't identified yet.  Individual applications run correctly using reverse proxy. But when I activate both, one of them gives the error: `AH00128: File does not exist: /var/www/html/myapp2/`. Configuration files are identical.

Answer (score 0):

**Here are my config for setting up multiple projects apache | windows | wsgi**

**httpd.conf**

```
LoadFile "c:/python37/python37.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/python37/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp37-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "c:/python37"

# site 1 config
WSGIScriptAlias /site1 "C:/Payslips/payslips_app/wsgi.py" application-group=site1

<Directory "C:/Payslips/payslips_app/">
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

Alias /static "C:/Payslips/static/"
<Directory "C:/Payslips/static/">
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# site 2 config
WSGIScriptAlias /site2 "C:/Subsistance-Payments-System/subsistance_payment/wsgi.py" application-group=site2

<Directory "C:/Subsistance-Payments-System/subsistance_payment/">
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

**site1 wsgi.py**

```
import os
import sys
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

sys.path.append('C:/Payslips/')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'payslips_app.settings'
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**site2 wsgi.py**

```
import os
import sys
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

sys.path.append('C:/Subsistance-Payments-System/')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'subsistance_payment.settings'
application = get_wsgi_application()
```